# PhpStorm Code Style 'Space - Within - Brackets' not functioning

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm, code-formatting, square-bracket

I am working on a PHP Laravel project with a team that requires spaces within brackets like this:

```
 $t = $one[ 0 ];
```

I attempted to accomplish this by set the following requirement in the Code Style Preference:

[image]

The highlights show that spaces should be added within brackets as needed.  However, after saving and restarting, I do not get this style applied, no matter how many time I press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd>.

Worse still, PhpStorm strips out the spaces that already exist within brackets, which causes a huge headache when I try to auto format existing code.

So this:

[image]

Is reformatted and becomes this:

[image]

I've set up other custom code style setting, and the other custom setting are getting applied.

Could someone offer some help with fixing this style problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option works just fine. It is for accessing individual array elements (e.g. `$t = $one[ 0 ];`).

But on your screenshots, where it does not work... it's array initializer (in other words, `$var = array('aaa', 'bbb');`)... and for that you need to use appropriate option -- **"Array initializer parentheses"** (which is just a bit below of what you have tried above).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, You are right.  The "Brackets" option does not affect array initializer brackets.  Also, The "Array initializer parentheses" option formats array initializer brackets too.